# Homebrew upgrade yarn installed node while I've already using nvm

Tags: node.js, homebrew, yarnpkg

I was upgrading my yarn with homebrew, I've already using nvm, but homebrew installed node 11 automatically for me.

When I type `which node`, I can see that I'm still using my nvm version of node 8.

So how do I properly remove my homebrew installed node 11.

I know that I can type `$ brew uninstall node`, but will there be any side effects?

I can not simply type `$ brew uninstall node`, it show error for me.

```
Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/node/11.12.0
because it is required by yarn, which is currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node
```

### Update

After I reinstall yarn with homebrew when I use yarn to execute package.json scripts, it shows me this error:

```
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is 
/var/folders/yw/wsrk1t713x13_5q52_dgjy_80000gn/T/yarn--1554024356098-0.4116378701167074/node but npm is using 
/Users/wangzhiyong/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary 
npm was executed with.
```

Reinstalling is not working, I think I just ruined my environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one  : `yarn config set scripts-prepend-node-path /usr/local/bin/node`